# Cziffra's cadenza in Hungarian Rhapsody No. 6

Tags: piano, sheet-music, transcription

I've been recently listening to the below interpretation of Liszt's Hungarian Rhapsody #6 by György Cziffra.

Between 1:40 and 1:50, he improvises a custom cadenza which I couldn't find written out. Would you happen to know what it is or where/how I could obtain the notes? I'd be interested in playing this (I'm currently learning this rhapsody), but it seems too complicated for me to write down by ear.

Comment: It sounds and looks very "Cziffra". So, you could study his arrangements and transcriptions of him playing (you can find some on YouTube at least) to learn about his embellishment vocabulary. Maybe then you can write it down yourself.

Answer (score 2):

That part is in [the original](https://imslp.org/wiki/Hungarian_Rhapsody_No.6,_S.244/6_(Liszt,_Franz)) (see the last two measures of the fourth page).

The problem could be that you have an arrangement of the piece (i.e., not the original, unabridged version).

---

Wait, slow down a minute. You mentioned tabs. Are you by any chance playing this on a guitar? If so, the editor might have decided to cut those two bars for their sheer complexity or extreme range on an instrument like the guitar.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have been misleading with the wording. I am playing this on the piano. I've also found the PDF you linked to, and the original cadenza is **not** what Cziffra plays. If you listen to it, you will hear that the last part of the last bar is not a simple scale, but it goes up, down, up, down, and then up again.

Comment: What do "tabs" have to do with it, then? o.O

Comment: "Tab" is short for tablature, the system used to indicate fingering on instruments, commonly the guitar.